# Simple Join understanding in mySql -- Records to flat file

Tags: mysql

Given the following table structure:  I need to get the records in a human readable flat file:

```
    CREATE  TABLE `formsfiles`.`Teams` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Sharks');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Jets');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Fish');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Dodgers');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Pigs');

CREATE  TABLE `Players` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Team_ID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jim', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tom', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Harry', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Dave', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tim', '3');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Trey', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jay', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Steve', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Ziggy', '5');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Chris', '4');
```

I would like the output from the players table:

```
    ID     Name     Team_ID     Team
1      Jim      1           Sharks

2      Tom      1           Sharks

3      Harry    2           Jets

4      Dave     2           Jets
```

I assume this is a simple join,  but not being a SQL guy Im stepping all over he syntax and can't seem to get it.  (kindly excuse the elementary nature of the question)

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.ID, p.Name, t.ID as Team_ID, t.Name as Team
from formsfiles.Teams t inner join Players p on p.Team_ID = t.ID
```

Comment: Thanks.  I know it was a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is the query you're after:

```
SELECT  Players.ID, Players.Name, Team.ID, Team.Name
FROM    Players 
        JOIN Teams 
            ON Players.Team_ID = Teams.ID
```

But you should really read a bit about joins and sql in general, it's quite usefull stuff.

Comment: I appreciate your spelling it out so clearly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.ID, p.Name, t.ID, t.Name
FROM players p
JOIN teams t on t.ID = p.Team_ID
```

Comment: Thanks  I appreciate the help.